# Зачем нужны константы в классе Boolean

Tags: java

А для чего использовать Boolean.TRUE, если есть уже true, тольки ли чтоб получить объектный тип?

Answer (score 2):

Это сделано для того, чтобы на каждый вызов `java.lang.Boolean.valueOf`не создавать новый объект, а возвращать статическое поле данного класса.

Comment: А разве Boolean не использует пул объектива при создании?

Comment: загляни в реализацию класса, нет там никакого пула, вместо него используются именно эти поля. При автобоксинге тоже  кстати  вызывается valueOf, именно с той же целью -  плодить как можно меньше новых объектов.